# where to store variable on RoR on heroku that needs to change several times a day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Do I use an Heroku environment variable? can I change the value from within Rails?

I used a file (File.read and File.write) but Heroku's ephemeral system does not save the new value stored in the file.

Comment: You can use any [persistent data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores). Pick one and go nuts.

Comment: I have postgresql installed. Should I just create a table for this variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use global settings variable, you can use this https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings. We used this in some projects

Answer (score 1):

Use Postgres then. Make a simple model to store your settings.

Loading a Postgres record takes, typically, less than a millisecond. The cost of loading this once on Rails startup is inconsequential.